# Why does the error: SyntaxError: f-string: mismatched '(', '{', or '[' in a block of code occur in Python?

Tags: python, f-string, square-bracket, braces

I have tried to make a `Person` class and while printing using f-strings an `SyntaxError` came up. Do you know why?

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, age, firstName, lastName='', hobbies=None):
    self.age = age
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.hobbies = hobbies

  def printDescription():
    firstPart = f'My name is {self.firstName + {' ' if self.lastName != '' else ''} + self.lastName} and I am {self.age}'
    secondPart = f', also I like {self.hobbies}' if self.hobbies else ''
    print(firstPart + secondPart)

me = Person.__init__(me, 500†, 'Ken', 'Tran', 'programming')

me.printDescription()
```

> SyntaxError: f-string: mismatched '(', '{', or '['

Does anyone know why this is happening? (like a typo) I think I am just not looking closely, or is there a reason to this?

† some random number, not my real age

Comment: Each variable in the f-string should be enclosed in braces. eg you have: `{self.firstName + {`.  You also have: `like {self.hobbies}` which seems fine.

Comment: I would recommend a `@property` method that returns the full name.

Comment: Are you trying to do logic in the fstring brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `'` as the delimiters of the f-string, the `'` after `{` will terminate the string, resulting in an unmatched `{`. Use different delimiters around the string and for the strings that are inside.

Also, there's no need to use `{}` inside `{}`. That will create a `set` object. Use `()` for grouping.

```
firstPart = f"My name is {self.firstName + (' ' if self.lastName != '' else '') + self.lastName} and I am {self.age}"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm a beginner to Python so this is new to me.